# Insert recycler view item with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, chat

I've integrated chat in my project so I have a recycler view for messages. How can I insert each new item (from bottom) with animation? I've already tried to insert items with `notifyItemRangeChanged()` and `notifyItemInserted()` but the animation is not that smooth

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me
In your adapter,

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bottom_up);
 holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);

Answer (score 0):

> The `DefaultItemAnimator` is responsible for a *smooth transition* when the adapter is notified !

So, Add the following when you initialize your recyclerview ...before `notifyItemInserted(poisition)`

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Comment: DefaultItemAnimator is used by the RecyclerView by default